# C++: Linker error

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando usar la libreria Freeglut, pero al momento de enlazar los archivos .a me da los siguientes errores:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibfreeglut
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibfreeglut_static
```

pero si cambio las extensiones de .a a .lib si funciona ¿Porque pasa esto?

Comando:

```
g++ main.cpp -omain.exe -std=c++11 -I"C:\\Freeglut\\include" -L"C:\\Freeglut\\lib\\x64 -llibfreeglut -llibfreeglut_static"
```

Comment: Por favor muestra el comando que usas para ejecutar gcc o ld.

Comment: Ya agregue el comando

Comment: Si la biblioteca se llama`libfreeglut`, se debe usar la opción `-l` de esta forma: `-lfreeglut` (se indica el nombre de la biblioteca sin el prefijo *lib*).

Comment: Gracias, me funciono correctamente!